# .net how to persist multiple popups after mouse hover

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, mouseover, mousehover

In my graph of events vs. time, when I mouse hover over an event, a popup shows details of event.
But when I hover over another event, first popup disappears and 2nd popup shows.

How can I get any number of previous popups to persist (remain shown)?

Then, I want double-click mouse to disappear all popups.

Here is present code that popsup details which persist until mouse hovers at a different event...

```
    Private Sub MONEY_Chart_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles MONEY_Chart.MouseMove
        DIM this_pos AS INTEGER
        DIM next_pos AS INTEGER
        DIM total_buy_cost               
        DIM total_sell_proceeds          
        DIM _order_execution_shares      
        DIM _order_execution_type        
        DIM _order_execution_commission  
        DIM _order_execution_orderID     
        DIM window_price_diff            
        DIM ob_budget                    
        DIM ob_shares                    
        DIM ob_cash_equity               
        DIM latest_share_equity          
        DIM ob_equity                    
        DIM ob_window                    
        DIM ob_direction                 
        DIM trade_cycle_number
   

        DIM pos = e.Location
        if NOT ISNOTHING( prevPosition ) 
        IF NOT prevPosition.IsEmpty
        IF pos = prevPosition
            return
        end if
        end if
        end if

            

        prevPosition = pos
        DIM results = MONEY_Chart.HitTest(pos.X, pos.Y, false,
                                        DataVisualization.Charting.ChartElementType.DataPoint)
        For Each  result in results
                    
            if (result.ChartElementType = DataVisualization.Charting.ChartElementType.DataPoint)
                    
                DIM prop as DataVisualization.Charting.DataPoint = result.Object 
                if NOT ISNOTHING( prop )
                    DIM trade_type AS STRING = result.Series.Name
                    DIM opcode
                    SELECT trade_type
                        Case "timestamp_market_price"               ' share price
                            opcode = "Price"

                        Case "execution_buy_price"          
                            opcode = "Buy"

                        Case "execution_sell_price"
                            opcode = "Sell"

                        CASE "event_equity"
                            opcode = "OB TOTAL EQ"
                    End Select
                    IF trade_type <> prev_trade_type
                            IF DIAG_MSGS THEN Controller.con( event_number & " " & trade_type )
                            prev_trade_type = trade_type
                    End If

                    DIM pointXPixel = result.ChartArea.AxisX.ValueToPixelPosition(prop.XValue)
                    DIM pointYPixel = result.ChartArea.AxisY.ValueToPixelPosition(prop.YValues(0) )

                    ' check if the cursor is really close to the point (2 pixels around the point)
                    if (Math.Abs(pos.X - pointXPixel) < 2 AND
                        Math.Abs(pos.Y - pointYPixel) < 2)
                    
                        ' if buy or sell point, display tooltip of trade details for Min. time period:
                            DIM is_trade_point = ( opcode = "Buy" OR opcode = "Sell"  )
                            IF  is_trade_point
                                hold_timestamp = Controller.present_seconds()
                                keep_showing_trade = TRUE
                                IF DIAG_MSGS THEN Controller.con( event_number & " is_trade_point")
                            END IF
                        IF Controller.elapsed_seconds(  hold_timestamp ) > 2
                                keep_showing_trade = FALSE
                                IF DIAG_MSGS THEN Controller.con( event_number & " hold_timestamp = FALSE")
                        End If

                        ' Trade point and Showing trade point details?
                        IF is_trade_point   OR  ( NOT is_trade_point AND NOT keep_showing_trade )
                            IF DIAG_MSGS THEN Controller.con( event_number & " show is_trade_point " & is_trade_point )

'                           trade_TOOLTIP.RemoveAll()
                            event_timestamp_DATETIME = Date.FROMOADATE( prop.XValue )
                            DIM money_file_index AS INTEGER = 0
'                           SELECT trade_type
'                               CASE  "execution_buy_price" , "execution_sell_price",  "event_equity"   
                                    this_pos = 0                                 
                                    ' Get trade's details:
                                        FOR money_file_index = 0 TO final_file_index 
                                            ' At event at mouse, ie. event's point in time?
                                            IF trade_event_DATETIME( money_file_index ) = event_timestamp_DATETIME
                                                ' (Y-axis is latest price, buy share price, or sell share price.  
                                                '   All other trade details come from subsequent money file line after these, ie. begin with ob_total_equity, etc...)
                                                ' Select remnant trade details after ob_total_equity, ie.: total_buy_cost ...
                                                DIM money_file_line AS STRING = trade_remnant( money_file_index )    ' if buy or sell,  total_buy_cost etc.

                                                this_pos = 1
                                                next_pos = TRIM( Controller.INSTR(  this_pos, money_file_line, ",") + 1 )          
                                                total_buy_cost = TRIM( MID( money_file_line, this_pos, next_pos - this_pos - 1 ))

                                                this_pos = next_pos
                                                next_pos = TRIM( Controller.INSTR(  this_pos, money_file_line, ",") + 1 )          
                                                total_sell_proceeds = TRIM( MID( money_file_line, this_pos, next_pos - this_pos - 1 ))

                                                this_pos = next_pos
                                                next_pos = TRIM( Controller.INSTR(  this_pos, money_file_line, ",") + 1 )          
                                                _order_execution_shares = TRIM( MID( money_file_line, this_pos, next_pos - this_pos - 1 ))

                                                this_pos = next_pos
                                                next_pos = TRIM( Controller.INSTR(  this_pos, money_file_line, ",") + 1 )          
                                                _order_execution_type = TRIM( MID( money_file_line, this_pos, next_pos - this_pos - 1 ))

                                                this_pos = next_pos
                                                next_pos = TRIM( Controller.INSTR(  this_pos, money_file_line, ",") + 1 )          
                                                _order_execution_commission = TRIM( MID( money_file_line, this_pos, next_pos - this_pos - 1 ))

                                                this_pos = next_pos
                                                next_pos = TRIM( Controller.INSTR(  this_pos, money_file_line, ",") + 1 )          
                                                _order_execution_orderID = TRIM( MID( money_file_line, this_pos, next_pos - this_pos - 1 ))

                                                this_pos = next_pos
                                                next_pos = TRIM( Controller.INSTR(  this_pos, money_file_line, ",") + 1 )          
                                                window_price_diff = TRIM( MID( money_file_line, this_pos, next_pos - this_pos - 1 ))

                                                this_pos = next_pos
                                                next_pos = TRIM( Controller.INSTR(  this_pos, money_file_line, ",") + 1 )          
                                                ob_budget = TRIM( MID( money_file_line, this_pos, next_pos - this_pos - 1 ))

                                                this_pos = next_pos
                                                next_pos = TRIM( Controller.INSTR(  this_pos, money_file_line, ",") + 1 )          
                                                ob_shares = TRIM( MID( money_file_line, this_pos, next_pos - this_pos - 1 ))

                                                this_pos = next_pos
                                                next_pos = TRIM( Controller.INSTR(  this_pos, money_file_line, ",") + 1 )          
                                                ob_cash_equity = TRIM( MID( money_file_line, this_pos, next_pos - this_pos - 1 ))

                                                this_pos = next_pos
                                                next_pos = TRIM( Controller.INSTR(  this_pos, money_file_line, ",") + 1 )          
                                                latest_share_equity = TRIM( MID( money_file_line, this_pos, next_pos - this_pos - 1 ))

                                                this_pos = next_pos
                                                next_pos = TRIM( Controller.INSTR(  this_pos, money_file_line, ",") + 1 )          
                                                ob_equity = TRIM( MID( money_file_line, this_pos, next_pos - this_pos - 1 ))

                                                this_pos = next_pos
                                                next_pos = TRIM( Controller.INSTR(  this_pos, money_file_line, ",") + 1 )          
                                                ob_window = TRIM( MID( money_file_line, this_pos, next_pos - this_pos - 1 ))

                                                this_pos = next_pos
                                                next_pos = TRIM( Controller.INSTR(  this_pos, money_file_line, ",") + 1 )          
                                                ob_direction = TRIM( MID( money_file_line, this_pos, next_pos - this_pos - 1 ))

                                                this_pos = next_pos
                                                trade_cycle_number = TRIM( MID( money_file_line, this_pos ) )

                                                EXIT FOR
                                            End If
                                        Next
                                        IF this_pos = 0 THEN STOP ' ..and fix fault.  trade not found
'                           END SELECT



                            DIM price_at_mouse = Controller.two_decimal_fraction( prop.YValues(0) )     ' trade share price at time point
                            
                            DIM trade_event_index = trade_index( money_file_index )
                            trade_details = ""
                            ' Depending on type of event, ie. market price (no trade details), exec buy or sell, event equity (no trade details)
                            SELECT trade_type
                                CASE "timestamp_market_price"           
                                    trade_details &=  opcode & " $" & price_at_mouse.TOSTRING & "/share at " & event_timestamp_DATETIME

                                CASE                             "execution_buy_price" , "execution_sell_price"         
                                    DIM derived_ob_equity = INT( VAL( ob_cash_equity )  + VAL( latest_share_equity ))       
                                    IF derived_ob_equity <> ob_equity
                                        STOP'and debug.
                                    END IF

                                CASE                                                                            "event_equity"
                                    IF trade_event_equity( money_file_index ) > 0
                                        ' Translate eq in terms of price into dollars:
                                        ob_equity =  trade_event_equity( money_file_index )
                                        IF ob_equity < 1
                                            ob_equity = Controller.two_decimal_fraction( ob_equity )
                                        ELSE
                                            ob_equity = Controller.no_decimal_fraction(ob_equity)
                                        END IF
                                    END IF
                                    trade_details &=  opcode & " $" & ob_equity & " at " & event_timestamp_DATETIME
                            END SELECT
                            DIM trade_ID  = trade_details
                            


                            SELECT trade_type
                                CASE  "execution_buy_price" , "execution_sell_price"    
                                    ' Execution status...
                                    trade_details &=  "Trade #" & 1+trade_event_index    & "  " & event_timestamp_DATETIME
                                    trade_details &=  VBCRLF &  VBCRLF & UCASE ( _order_execution_type ) _
                                                    & " " & _order_execution_shares & " shares" _
                                                    & " @ " &   " $" & Controller.two_decimal_fixed( price_at_mouse.TOSTRING ) 
                                                    
                                    set_tip( "commission", " $",           _order_execution_commission   )
                                    IF trade_type = "execution_buy_price"
                                    set_tip( "net buy cost             ", " $",           total_buy_cost                )
                                    END IF
                                    IF trade_type = "execution_sell_price"
                                    set_tip( "net sell proceeds        ", " $",           total_sell_proceeds           )
                                    END IF
                                    ' Financial status...
                                    tip_blank_line()
                                    set_tip( "budget                  ", " $",           ob_budget                     )
                                    set_tip( "shares                  ", " ",           ob_shares                     )
                                    set_tip( "cash flow      ", " $",           graph_cash_flow( money_file_index ).TOSTRING                     )
                                    set_tip( "equity cash             ", " $",           ob_cash_equity                )
                                    set_tip( "equity shares        ", " $",           latest_share_equity           )
                                    set_tip( "equity                  ", " $",           ob_equity.TOSTRING                     )

                                    ' Scheduling parameters...
                                    tip_blank_line()
                                    set_tip( "spread price diff          ", " $",           window_price_diff             ) ' ..upon exec, before sched
                                    'SELECT ob_direction
                                    'CASE -1:   ob_direction = "descend"
                                    'CASE 0:        ob_direction = "fluc"
                                    'CASE 1:        ob_direction = "rise"
                                    'END SELECT
                                    set_tip( "Prev direction             ", " ",           ob_direction                  )
                                    set_tip( "price state                ", " ",         UCASE(  ob_window )                     )
                                    tip_blank_line()
                                    set_tip( "orderID   ", " ",           _order_execution_orderID      )
                                    set_tip( "trade cyc   ", " ",           "#" & trade_cycle_number      )
                                     
                                CASE ELSE
                                    set_tip( "cash flow      ", " $",           graph_cash_flow( money_file_index ).TOSTRING                     )
                                    set_tip( "trade cyc   ", " ",           "#" & trade_cycle_number      )
                            End Select


                            ' Inhib popup if price event but price event inhibited?
                            IF CheckBox_popup_price_events.Checked OR opcode <> "Price"
                                trade_TOOLTIP.Show( trade_details,              
                                                    MONEY_Chart,
                                                    pos.X, 
                                                    pos.Y - 15)
                                event_number += 1

                                IF trade_ID <> prev_trade_ID
                                    prev_trade_ID = trade_ID

                                    'IF opcode <> "Price"
                                    '   '  append trade details to WORK\MONEY GUI TRADE DETAILS .txt:
                                    '   Clipboard.SetText( trade_details )
                                    '   Controller.append_text_file( work_pathname, VBCRLF & VBCRLF & VBCRLF & NOW & VBCRLF & VBCRLF &  trade_details )
                                    'END IF
                                    ' Set log destination to target APP DATA :
                                    Controller.remove_lowest_directory(  Controller.log_pathname )
                                    Controller.log_pathname =  money_file_path_TextBox.TEXT  & "log MONEY GUI .txt"
                                    Controller.log( VBCRLF & "TRADE " &  trade_details )
                                END IF
                            END IF
                        END IF


                    END IF
                END IF
            END IF      
        NEXT        
            
        
    End Sub
```

Comment: You have to instantiate multiple popups. You'd need to show us your current code so that we could show you how.

Comment: Here you go  ...

Comment: Sorry, I understand that you would call `Show` on a tool tip. I need to see how you're creating your tool tips. I need the full code. A [mcve] is what I need.

Comment: You also know that `. . .` doesn't compile. You need to provide code that we can work with.

Comment: Enig:  I put full code.

Comment: Don't forget to do a @Enigmativity if you want to ensure the person gets a notification.

Answer (score 1):

Your code appears to only have a single `ToolTip` instantiated. A single `ToolTip` can only be shown at one time. If you try to show it again it just moves to the new location.

To have multiple tool tips shown you need to instantiate multiple tool tips.

Here's a complete winforms example.

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    private Button Button1 = new Button();
    private Button Button2 = new Button();
    private Label Label1 = new Label();

    private List<ToolTip> _tooltips = new List<ToolTip>();

    private Random _random = new Random();
    
    public Form1()
    {
        Button1.Width = 120;
        Button1.Height = 20;
        Button1.Top = 24;
        Button1.Text = "Click Me";
        
        Button1.Click += (s, e) =>
        {
            var tooltip = new ToolTip();
            tooltip.ToolTipTitle = $"ToolTip {_tooltips.Count + 1}";
            _tooltips.Add(tooltip);
            tooltip.Show($"ToolTip {_tooltips.Count}", this, _random.Next(0, this.Width - 20), _random.Next(80, this.Height - 50));
            Label1.Text = $"ToolTip Count: {_tooltips.Count}";
        };

        Button2.Width = 120;
        Button2.Height = 20;
        Button2.Top = 24;
        Button2.Left = 140;
        Button2.Text = "Clear";

        Button2.Click += (s, e) =>
        {
            foreach (var tooltip in _tooltips)
            {
                tooltip.Dispose();
            }
            _tooltips.Clear();
            Label1.Text = $"ToolTip Count: {_tooltips.Count}";
        };

        Label1.Width = 120;
        Label1.Height = 20;
        Label1.Text = "Not Yet Clicked";
        
        this.Controls.Add(Label1);
        this.Controls.Add(Button1);
        this.Controls.Add(Button2);
    }
}
```

When I run it and click the `Click Me` button multiple times I get this:

[image: Form1]

Don't forget to clean up after you display your multiple tool tips - you always need to dispose of each one otherwise your app will eventually crash without enough resources.